# To omit @Autowired via constructor injection, which Lombok constructor annotation(s) should be used? (@NoArgs,@AllArgs,@ReqArgs)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, lombok

According to Spring, @Autowired can be omitted if constructor injection is used and there is only one constructor.

> As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a constructor is no longer necessary if the target bean only defines one constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which one to use.

Is using @NoArgsConstructor sufficient for Spring Boot projects?

My instructor is using constructor injection and avoiding @Autowired, while using both @NoArgsConstructor and @AllArgsConstructor annotations.

Doesn't that constitute "having multiple constructors"? If not, why?

I have also used @NoArgs, @AllArgs, and also @RequiredArgs. But I cannot determine if injection is working properly and whether @Autowired is needed.

Comment: @RequiredArgs with final fields.

Comment: For controller, service, etc that is perfect.
But what about model entities? Are they out of DI scope in this regard? Or should I use @NoArgs for example?
Such as;
public class Book {
    "at"Id
    "at"GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int price;

Comment: Model entities are out of DI scope.